# Linking events participants and contributions

Tags: civicontribute, civievent

We are currently batch importing data from our previous homemade event management system.

So far, we've managed to import contaributions and event's registrations for each user but we are stucked in the process of matching those contributions (event fees) with each event and updating the registration (paid status).

How could we proceed ?

We are running CiviCRM 4.6.2 on WP 4.2

Comment: I posted on this exact same issue some months ago on the (old) civicrm forum. (http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35287.0.html) It seems to me this need some coding into core. My suggestion is that this could use the same mechanism as the 'Soft Credit' functionality. Probably the new payment order api in 4.7 would be better fit to accomodate this. In the meantime: database hacking of the matching table I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a create participant record in civicrm_participant table which will have the Event Id in the table, participant and contribution should be linked using civicrm_participant_payment which will have contribution_id and participant_id. This is how you have to do

One more suggestion: before doing anything data import install a fresh copy of civicrm and delete all the relevant table records and make a test process by creating Event and registering the event for an member and look which are the tables been affect and please update the values based on the test

Comment: Thank you ! you made my day !
Is there a way to link it within civicrm ? Our volunteer might need this in the future.

Comment: I think the question refers to an existing install.  You definitely cover the "What" ie. linked using civicrm_participant_payment but I believe the op wants to do this in the UI or via script for existing records.

Comment: Is there a way to link it within civicrm? what do you want to know. Please be bit clear so I can explain you better - thanks

Comment: I'm currently importing data from our previous event management system.
When we process the data for civicrm we obtain 2 *.csv files to import. 1 event participant import and 1 contribution import. If i follow this process I get 2 unrelated list. I'd like to be able to tell civicrm to link the contribution and registration with one field in the csv import or afterward using the crm's UI.

Comment: you will find a table called civicrm_participant_payment just add the contribution_id and participant_id which links both the table